# How to prevent component from rendering child until data fetches

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have a Dashboard component that renders an array of cards with data fetched from a backend server. Users can create additional cards by submitting a form, which then redirects them back to the dashboard page.

My issue is that when the form is submitted, a javascript error 'cannot read property "includes" of undefined' is thrown and the dashboard does not render. If I manually refresh the page, the list renders as expected with the new card. I use Array.includes method to filter the cards based on the filterText state value. Does this error happen because the data has not been fetched when render is called? If so, how can I force the component to wait until there is data before rendering? Please see the components and redux action below.

```
const CardList = (props) =>  {

    const cards = props.cards.map(({ _id, title}) => {
            return (
                <Card key={_id} title={title} />
            )
        });

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <input onChange={ (e) => props.handleChange(e.target.value) } />
                <div className="row">
                    {cards}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
} 
export default CardList;

export class Dashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            filterText: ''
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchCards();
    } 

    handleChange = (filterText) => {
        this.setState({filterText});
    }

    render() {
        const cardList = this.props.cards.filter(card => 
            card.title.includes(this.state.filterText.trim().toLowerCase())
        );
        return (
            <div>
                <CardList cards={cardList}
                    handleChange={filterText => this.handleChange(filterText)} />
            </div>
        );
    }
};
function mapStateToProps({ cards: { cards }}) {
    return {
        cards,
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchCards})(Dashboard);

export class SurveyForm extends Component {
render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <form>
                 <Field component={CardField} type="text" 
                     label={'title'} name={'title'} key={'title'} />
                 <Button type="submit" onClick={() => submitCard(formValues, history)}>Next</Button>
               </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
REDUX ACTION DISPATCHER:
export const submitCard = (values, history) => async dispatch => {
    const res = await axios.post('/api/cards', values);

    try {
        dispatch({ type: SUBMIT_CARD_SUCCESS, payload: res.data });
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data })
    }
    catch(err) {
        dispatch({ type: SUBMIT_CARD_ERROR, error: err });
    }

    history.push('/cards');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to what @JasonWarta mentioned, it's worth noting that React does not render anything when `false`, `null`, or `undefined` is returned, so you can usually use `&&` to be more succinct than using the conditional ("ternary") operator:

```
render() {
  return this.props.cards && (
    <div>
      <CardList 
        cards={this.props.cards.filter(card => card.title.includes(this.state.filterText.trim().toLowerCase())}
        handleChange={filterText => this.handleChange(filterText)}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Because `&&` short-circuits, the latter part won't be evaluated so you can avoid `TypeError`s, and the component will also render no content (same as when you return `null`).

Comment: I really liked that approach if you don't need to render anything else. Thanks, noted :)

Comment: It works mixed into other content as well. If a component has a child that's null/undefined/false, it won't render as well. This lets you do inline conditionals within a tree.

Comment: @Jacob thanks, this makes sense. However it is not working, so i'm thinking the issue is elsewhere. Looking at the type Error, it's being thrown in the redux action final line. "history.push('/cards')". Does that make a difference? I can edit to post the reducer as well if it would help.

Comment: It becomes slightly unreadable as soon as we have couple more conditionals, so another approach could is to separate out the condition piece in a separate function itself.

Answer (score 0):

I've used ternary operators in this kind of situation. You may need to adjust the check portion of the pattern, depending on what your redux pattern is returning. `null` value is returned if `this.props.cards` is falsey.

```
render() {
    return (
        {this.props.cards
            ?
                <div>
                    <CardList 
                        cards={this.props.cards.filter(card => card.title.includes(this.state.filterText.trim().toLowerCase())}
                        handleChange={filterText => this.handleChange(filterText)}
                    >
                    </CardList>
                </div>
            :
                null
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to other answers you can return something else suitable if there is no data in your render function with an if statement. I prefer moving functions like your filter one outside of render. Maybe one other (better?) approach is doing that filter in your mapStateToProps function.

Also, if I'm not wrong you don't need to pass anything to your handleChange function. Because you are getting filterText back from CardList component then setting your state.

```
cardList = () => this.props.cards.filter(card => 
            card.title.includes(this.state.filterText.trim().toLowerCase()));

render() {
 if ( !this.props.cards.length ) {
        return <p>No cards</p>
        // or return <SpinnerComponent />
    }
 return (
            <div>
                <CardList cards={this.cardList()}
                    handleChange={this.handleChange} />
            </div>
        );       
 }
```